# About socket in Android

Tags: android, sockets

```
package androidclient.test;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class AndroidClient_Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //System.out.println("Has requested");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_client_);
        //System.out.println("Has requested");
        try {
            java.net.Socket sc = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.100"),2024);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Has requested");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_android_client_, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The application has run into server. It has output in the monitor. But after I start client, it can not connect server. I also add some input sentence in oncreate() method. It has no response and did not output exception.

Could anyone give me a guide? Thanks very much!

Comment: The code you pasted does nothing but create a socket. It's not clear what your actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the socket.getInputStream() and socket.getOutputStream to communicate via the socket.

See the client example on http://zerioh.tripod.com/ressources/sockets.html